# How Oraclde database should be SQLS

Tags: oracle, encryption, jdbc, ssl-certificate, database-administration

Security department of my company said to our application team, "your application have to use sql**s** to connect your database."
SSL is integrated into our application but our database has not certificate.

On the other hand, we use below connection string to connect DB;
spring.foo.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.126.1.12:1521/foo

1. What kind of releation between jdbc:oracle:this between sqls?
2. What does it mean ***"your application have to use sqls to connect your
   database."***?
3. What should we do?

Please help...
Thanks.

Comment: I believe your security team is easier to access and ask than post a question about someone's terminology (assiming you've done enough research trying to decode "sqls" by yourself, that is the ferst step before asking)

Comment: They could mean SSL/TLS or TCPS - like [this Oracle article](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc-tlsv12-jks-or-oracle-wallets-122-and-lower), or [this SE post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/277955/how-to-configure-tcps-in-jdbc-thin-client-for-oracle) for example. But there's no point investigating or attempting to implement something without getting confirmation that it will actually address your security department's requirements. Only they can tell you what they expect you to do to be compliant.

Comment: They said to us only "Each communication have to be done in HTTPS, LDAPs and SMTPs, SQLs." Everything OK but SQLS is not clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step solution
1.Create certificate for DB type.
2.Create private key
3.Integrate certificate into DB server.